# Extract innerText from one cell

Tags: vba, excel, html-parsing

I am trying to extract only the inner text of rightmost cell in row in an HTML-table. This is a small section of the HTML code. The row contains 810 cells and the TR tag holds 811 TD tags:

```
</tr><tr align="center" id="spt_inner_row_2"><td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white">
&nbsp;300 - 305&nbsp;
</td><td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white">
&nbsp;300 - 305&nbsp;
</td><td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white">
&nbsp;300 - 305&nbsp;
</td><td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white">
&nbsp;300 - 305&nbsp;
```

The code I currently use successfully extracts the data from each cell and pastes it in column A of the active sheet:

```
Sub GetData()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
    Dim r As Long

    'For login use
    Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
    Dim UserNameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement

    URL = "https://www.whatever.com"

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True

        'Wait for page to load
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Set HTMLdoc = .document

            'Enter login info
            Set LoginForm = HTMLdoc.forms(0)

            'Username
            Set UserNameInputBox = LoginForm.elements("username")
            UserNameInputBox.Value = "username"

            'Password
            Set PasswordInputBox = LoginForm.elements("password")
            PasswordInputBox.Value = "password"

            'Get the form input button and click it

            Set SignInButton = LoginForm.elements("doLogin")
            SignInButton.Click

            'Wait for the new page to load

            Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

        'Auto-navigate to start page, so we need to navigate once more

        .navigate URL

        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

        End With


    'Specify how to recognize data to extract
    Set TDelements = HTMLdoc.getElementById("spt_inner_row_2").getElementsByTagName("TD")


    r = 0

    For Each TDelement In TDelements

        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.innerText

        r = r + 1

    Next

End Sub
```

What I really need is to extract only the last (rightmost) cell in the HTML table row. Any suggestions?

Comment: Refer this [**link1**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643483/trying-to-fetch-data-from-webpage-with-a-vba-code-but-sometimes-it-works-and-so/17666816#17666816), [**Link2**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844342/pulling-upside-downside-capture-ratio-from-morningstar-com/15853293#15853293) & [**Link3**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959008/import-web-data-in-excel-using-vba/15962055#15962055)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IHTMLElementCollection` has a `length` property and an `item` property. The `item` property can take a numeric index but is zero-based so the last entry is at `length - 1`

```
Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection

Set TDelements = HTMLdoc.getElementById("spt_inner_row_2").getElementsByTagName("TD")

With TDelements
    MsgBox .Item(.Length - 1).InnerText
End With
```