# Getting data from Website back to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate a page scrape program in Excel using VBA but having difficulty getting the results from the webpage as the fields I want do not have id's, I have copied the source code below I think its contained within a table? how do you get the data using td Class and class?

```
<table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Date of Liability</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span class="bodytext">01 07 2014</span></td>
                    </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Date of First Registration</span></td>
                                <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span class="bodytext">02 07 2013</span></td>
                            </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Year of Manufacture</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span class="bodytext">2013</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Cylinder Capacity (cc)</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span class="bodytext">2993cc</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">CO&#8322; Emissions</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span class="bodytext">129 g/km</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Fuel Type</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span id="fueltype" class="bodytext">HEAVY OIL</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Export Marker</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span id="exportmarker" class="bodytext">N</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Vehicle Status</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span id="vehiclelicencestatus" class="bodytext">Licence Not Due</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Vehicle Colour</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span id="colour" class="bodytext">BLUE</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Vehicle Type Approval</span></td>
                        <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span class="bodytext">M1</span></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="vehicledetailstableleft"><span class="bodytextbold">Date of Last V5C Issued</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="vehicledetailstableright"><span class="bodytext">No Result Found</span> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Why not just use the built in Excel Web Query?

Comment: You can use `objIE.document.getElementsByTagname("tr")` to get all the table rows, then do the same thing on each tr to get the td elements. If you need to get the class  then look at the className property.

Comment: @user2140261 This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844342/pulling-upside-downside-capture-ratio-from-morningstar-com/15853293#15853293) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Tim is suggesting a code heavy way to do it, and it is technically correct.  I suggest the same thing repeatedly here:
[VBA spliting results from html imported table into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095050/vba-spliting-results-from-html-imported-table-into-excel/19276041#19276041)
Basically, use the macro recorder, and then create a HTML query for data.
see my blog post on this as well.
http://automatic-office.com/?p=344

Many ways to skin the cat, but this is the easy way.